# Question about the 'Stack' basic problem (C++)

Tags: c++, stl

I am a student studying basic algorithm.
I wrote a code to get the sum of all the elements by `stl:stack`.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

   

     int main(void)
        {
            ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
            cin.tie(0);
            int k; cin >> k;
            stack<int> s;
            int answer=0;
            while (k--)
            {
                int n; cin >> n;
                if (n == 0)
                {
                    s.pop();
                }
                else 
                {
                    s.push(n);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
            {
                answer = answer + s.top();
                s.pop();
            }
            cout << answer;
        }
```

Input:

```
5 5 4 3 2 1
```

Output:

```
6
```

As I intended, the result should be 15 but there is an error.
But if I replace `for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)` with `while(!s.empty())`, get normal results.
Is there a problem with `i <size()`? I'd appreciate it if you could answer.

Comment: Please study this too: [Why should I **not** `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)
 and [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) TL;DR; `bits/stdc++.h` is not a standard header file. I can't compile your program.

Comment: consider what happens to `s.size()` as you pop elements, try using a debugger

Comment: Unrelated: `int main(void)` - You don't need `void` there. That's a `C` thing.

Comment: Size changes everytime there's a pop.

Comment: Thank you. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the `for` loop terminating condition.

`for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)`

- Before the 1st iteration: `i = 0` and `s.size()` is `5` so `i < s.size()` is `true`
- Before the 2nd iteration: `i = 1` and `s.size()` is `4` so `i < s.size()` is `true`
- Before the 3rd iteration: `i = 2` and `s.size()` is `3` so `i < s.size()` is `true`
- Before the 4th iteration: `i = 3` and `s.size()` is `2` so `i < s.size()` is `false` and the 4th and 5th iteration never happens.

Because the `i` is being incremented while the `size()` is being decremented on every iteration (because of the `pop()` operation) this is effectively doing about half the necessary iterations which results in `answer = 1 + 2 + 3` (i.e., `answer = 6`).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69003313/4505712) shows a way to fix the `for` loop implementation but the `while(!s.empty())` loop you have in your question would be my preference.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Store size of stack in another variable before using in loop because when you use directly s.size() in loop . At each pop operation , it will change the size of stack every time ,therefore s.size() changes everytime

```
int size=s.size();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            answer = answer + s.top();
            s.pop();
        }
        cout << answer;
```

Comment: or just use while loop     `while(!s.empty()){ }`

Comment: Note the OP knows they can use `while(!s.empty())` they specifically asked why the `while` loop works but the `for` loop doesn't.